# Can't properly compare 2 JSON files in PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell, object, parsing, comparison

I've recently been working on a project that needs me to compare two JSON files and return the differences between both in PowerShell. I recently started to learn the language, and I've come across multiple issues.

I've tried checking all over the internet and forums from what I could understand of my issue, but nothing really worked.

I tried using `Compare-Object` but it returned me the whole JSON as a difference, transforming them into PsObjects, it kinda worked but I couldn't get the full path and broke at some point, etc...

My final attempt was to iterate over each property of my object and when I would encounter an object, I would simply "open" the object / "redirect" myself in it and so on... (basically, iterating in object & sub-objects).

It's almost working, thus I'm not sure why I've got an issue. Here's the code sample :

(note that $obj is one single PowerShell Object coming from a foreach loop (foreach $obj in $Obj) and $template is another PS object)

```
function Compare-Templates($obj, $template, $current_path)
{
    ForEach ($prop in $obj.PsObject.Properties) {
        Write-Host "$($prop.Name):$($prop.value)" -ForegroundColor Magenta
        Write-Host "$($current_path)$($prop.Name)" -ForegroundColor DarkBlue
        Write-Host ""
        
        if ($ObjectTypesName -contains $prop.TypeNameOfValue) {
            Write-Host "$($prop.Value) is a PsObject!" -ForegroundColor DarkRed
            Write-Host ""
            Write-Host "-------- Nested in $($prop.Name) --------" -ForegroundColor Yellow
            Compare-Templates $prop.value $template ($current_path + "$($prop.Name)/")
            Write-Host "-------- Out Nested --------" -ForegroundColor Yellow
            Write-Host ""
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
-------- Nested in oneObject --------
firstValue:1
oneObject/firstvalue
```

It would give me the value of the variables found and its path (I need it later on).

The issue :

In my JSON file, I can have an array inside a variable such as :

```
    "Object":  [    <-------- the array that gives the weird `SyncRoot` variables over and over 
                          {
                              "anotherObject":  {
                                                              "firstValue":  false,
                                                              "secondValue":  false
                                                          },
[...]
```

The program understands that the array can be accessed (it even gives me the content in "preview", e.g. `object:@(anotherObject=)`)

In my debug, it would say :

```
-------- Nested in OBJ--------
Count:1
OBJ/Count

Length:1
OBJ/Length

LongLength:1
OBJ/LongLength

Rank:1
OBJ/Rank

SyncRoot:@{object1=; object2=; object3=System.Object[]; object4=; object5=; object6=; object7=; object8=System.Object[]; object9=System.Object[]}
OBJ/SyncRoot
```

(Note that for security reasons I changed all variable names, but there is still a cohesion between them)

Everything found in the object is something which doesn't exist in my object, and I'm not sure where it's from (probably the array's "default" variable).

My question is : How could I access the array which is nested in my object, without looping indefinitely over the `SyncRoot` object?
Or should I use this hand-made method or is there an actual function / simple way to iterate over a PowerShell object, nest with other PowerShell objects OR comparing JSONs that would give me the full "path" of a variable with different values?

Note that it can iterate indefinitely such as `OBJ_which_has_an_array_like_the_example_above/SyncRoot/SyncRoot/SyncRoot/SyncRoot/SyncRoot/SyncRoot/Length` and so on...

Comment: Partial fix - try changing ```ForEach ($prop in $obj.PsObject.Properties) {``` to ```$jsonProperties = $obj.PsObject.Properties | where-object { $_.MemberType -eq "NoteProperty" }; ForEach ($prop in $jsonProperties) {```. At the moment you're comparing all of the underlying .Net object properties as well (e.g. ```Length```, ```SyncRoot``` on an array) but you only want to compare properties that represent json attributes.

Comment: Thanks. Now it doesn't print any of the garbage I didn't need, but it doesn't access any array either. I've been trying to figure out how I could get this done by working with GetType(), Get-Member but it looks like the array is exactly like any other objects I send. Any ideas to access them with your method, or doesn't it change the way I should do it? (if it just removed the useless components or changed the way it's handled aswell?)

Comment: Well I think I solved it myself. Instead of passing $prop.Value when I encountered and array, I would simply send $prop.Value[0]. I didn't check everything but as far as I can see the debug in the console it seems that it accessed all of the objects and "sub-objects". Thanks for the tip to exclude any of the underlying .Net properties, it's kinda useful and avoid having to manually terminate the program with 2/3 of the output being useless.